# Trying to call method rom fragmentB in fragmentA and having NPE

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I cant resolve this problem. I think FragmentTransaction work like "i create fragment i open it", but this going wrong. My problem is when i call method from FragmentB i got NPE like my values is not initialize. So whats going now.

Problem is here when i try to call method configureSettingsMenus with position on clicked item in Drawer.

```
     result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
//                settingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(position);
                result.closeDrawer();
//                ft.add(settingsFragment, "settingsFragment");
                if (settingsFragment != null && settingsFragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
                    settingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(position);
                    settingsFragment.show(ft, DIALOG_SETTINGS);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And here is method in fragment B

```
public void configureSettingsMenus(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case TRADING_HISTORY:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 0");
            break;
        case LEADER_BOARD:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 1");
            break;
        case SPECIAL_OFFER:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 2");
            break;
        case VIDEO_TUTORIALS:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 3");
            break;
        case FAQ:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 4");
            break;
        case CONTACT:
            settingsText.setText("fragment 5");
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}
```

I initialize all in Butterknife. Like u see u have settingsText i trying to setText for every picked position.

I got NPE on  `settingsText.setText in fragmentB`

and on   `settingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(position)` in fragmentA

Whats wrong? Any help approciate.

EDIT:

```
Process: com.example.andrzej.forexapp, PID: 2329
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.andrzej.forexapp.activities.fragments.SettingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(SettingsFragment.java:75)
                                                                                at com.example.andrzej.forexapp.activities.fragments.MainGameFragment$2.onItemClick(MainGameFragment.java:156)
                                                                                at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$5.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1716)
                                                                                at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$5.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1690)
                                                                                at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.FastAdapter$1.onClick(FastAdapter.java:492)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: post the logcat..

Comment: Your `settingsText` is null. You should check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice communicating directly between fragments. You have to write an interface in your fragment and let the attached activity to implement the interface.

In your fragment:

```
public interface DrawerClickCallbacks{
        public void onItemClick(int position);
    }
```

In your activity:

```
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    settingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(position);
}
```

You'll have to implement DrawerClickCallbacks in the activity attached to the fragment